# Do Charm/Hold Person or psionic equivalents work on Lycanthropes?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, monsters

Is a Lycanthrope affected by Charm/Hold person or similar psionic powers?

I see that it has the Shapchanger subtype, but I don't know what that implies here. Does that mean a human infected with lycanthropy is or is not affected by Charm Person and similar?

Is the answer different for natural Lycanthropes?

Comment: **An Aside:** While humans are usually the most common lycanthropic stock , *giants* can be lycanthropes, too; a were-roc storm giant, for example, is immune to *person* spells because it's a giant not a humanoid.

Answer (score 5):

### **Yes.**

There's nothing about the Shapechanger subtype that prevents them from being vulnerable to Hold Person, Charm Person, Dominate Person, or any other Compulsion based Mind-affecting spells.

You may be confusing Shapechanger's ability to override Polymorph effects with their own transformations with mindless creatures and their immunity to Mind-affecting spells.

Natural Lycanthropes don't have immunity to Mind-affecting spells either, so the answer is the same for either of them. Unless the creature already possesses a subtype that makes them immune to Mind-affecting spells, Charm Person, Hold person, etc. work as normal.

Answer (score 3):

**Yes**.

A humanoid lycanthrope would be affected by the spells you mention. Unless the original type and augmented subtype is explicitly mentioned to be immune.

---

**No.**

The answer isn't different for a natural lycanthrope.

---

**Why?**

Because they are still their original type, with shapechanger in addition. "The [augmented subtype](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/typesSubtypes.htm#augmentedSubtype) is always paired with the creature’s original type."

---

**Example of Subtype with an Immunity**

> [Fire Subtype](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/typesSubtypes.htm#fireSubtype)
>
> A creature with the fire subtype has **immunity to fire**. It has vulnerability to cold, which means it takes half again as much (+50%) damage as normal from cold, regardless of whether a saving throw is allowed, or if the save is a success or failure.

---

**Example of Subtype without an Immunity**

> [Shapechanger Subtype](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/typesSubtypes.htm#shapechangerSubtype)
>
> A shapechanger has the supernatural ability to assume one or more [alternate forms](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/specialAbilities.htm#alternateForm). Many magical effects allow some kind of shape shifting, and not every creature that can change shape has the shapechanger subtype.
>
> - The creature retains the special qualities of its original form. It does not gain any special qualities of its new form.